# How to find the associated type `IntoIter` when implementing `IntoIterator` by using iterator composition in Rust?

Tags: rust, iterator, associated-types

I am currently trying to implement a structure of arrays. I want to implement the IntoIterator for the SOA in a way that yields the base structure on the fly, as if I was iterating over an array of structures. Here is the to types: the structure and its SOA,

```
struct Particle {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    v: [f64; 3]
}

struct ParticleSOA {
    x: Vec<f64>,
    y: Vec<f64>,
    v: Vec<[f64; 3]>,
}
```

By using the 'izip!' macro from [itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.8/itertools/macro.izip.html), It is quite easy to build an iterator by zipping the `Vec`s of my SOA and mapping the produced tuples to the original structure. However I can't find out what Type to give to the associated type `IntoIter`required for the `IntoIterator` trait.

```
impl IntoIterator for ParticleSOA{
    type Item = Particle;

    type IntoIter = ???;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
       izip!(self.x,self.y,self.v).map(Particle::from)
    }
}
```

Is there a clever way to infer the type from my implementation of the `into_iter` function, Or my only choice is to work out the precise type created by the composition of iterator functions by hand?

**EDIT**

The secret was getting rid of closures, especially the one hidden in izip!
Itertools has a multizip function that produces a usable type.

```
impl IntoIterator for ParticleSOA {
    type Item = Particle;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        multizip((self.x, self.y, self.v)).map(Particle::from)
    }

    type IntoIter = Map<
        itertools::Zip<(
            std::vec::IntoIter<f64>,
            std::vec::IntoIter<f64>,
            std::vec::IntoIter<[f64; 3]>,
        )>,
        fn((f64, f64, [f64; 3])) -> Particle,
    >;
}
```

Note : My struct conveniently implements `From<(f64, f64, [f64; 3])>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return a boxed iterator, so in case your implementation changes, the return type wouldn't need to:

```rust
use itertools::izip; // 0.10.3

struct Particle {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    v: [f64; 3]
}

struct ParticleSOA {
    x: Vec<f64>,
    y: Vec<f64>,
    v: Vec<[f64; 3]>,
}

impl IntoIterator for ParticleSOA{
    type Item = Particle;

    type IntoIter = Box<dyn Iterator<Item=Self::Item>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
       Box::new(izip!(self.x,self.y,self.v).map(|(x, y, v)| Particle {x, y , v}))
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5157fa4c22d0346664c92537c73b6bcc)

Otherwise the type should be, as an approximation  something like :

`Map<Zip<(f64, f64, [f64; 3])>, Fn>`

a rather complicated type.

You can also make your own function, not implementing the trait:

```rust
impl ParticleSOA {
    #[inline]
    fn into_iter(self) -> impl Iterator<Item=Particle> {
        izip!(self.x, self.y, self.v).map(|(x, y, v)| Particle { x, y, v })
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a11c7de658282654cbcdad1a6b19e5bd)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply ! I was afraid I had to do that. Since I am creating a SOA to increase performances, isn't using a trait object a costly abstraction to replace manually creating my iterator with izip and map each time I want a for loop?

Comment: @Quettle, I dont think it would. Maybe the dynamic dispatch, but depending on where may be negligible . always take in mind that this abstractions are optimized by the compiler when possible. But you can make the test. Otherwise you could just make a function and inline it.

Comment: Ah yes very good suggestion! And the type problem in the function signature can be avoided with `-> impl Iterator<Item=Particle>` right?

Comment: @Quettle, yes, sadly the impl feature cannot be used in trait implementations still

Comment: And the closure hidden in izip doesn't help at all with standard generics. Thank you again, I'll mark the question solved.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to what @Netwave said, with the unstable feature [`type_alias_impl_trait`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63063) you can specify `impl Iterator` in an associated type:

```rust
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

impl IntoIterator for ParticleSOA {
    type Item = Particle;

    type IntoIter = impl Iterator<Item = Particle>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
       izip!(self.x,self.y,self.v).map(Particle::from)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f585d864f0fd58a6fb7d45512e8e2a35).